# R is unable to recognize NA's in my dataset

Tags: r

I am puzzled by the fact that R is unable to recognize the NA's in my dataset `daily`. A quick inspection of `daily` may lead one to believe that there are no NA's in the variable `OBLIGOR_ID`:

```
class(daily)
# "data.frame"

table(is.na(daily$OBLIGOR_ID))
#  FALSE
# 207775
```

However, if one draws the `OBLIGOR_ID`'s for all those observations whose `ADJUSTED_ORR` is 62512, one would find that

```
daily[daily$ADJUSTED_ORR==62512,c('OBLIGOR_ID')]

# [1]   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# [60]  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# [119] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# [178] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

is.na(daily[daily$ADJUSTED_ORR==62512,c('OBLIGOR_ID')])

# [1]   TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [36]  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [71]  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [106] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [141] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [176] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you try `is.na(daily[which(dat$ADJUSTED_ORR==62512),'OBLIGOR_ID'])`

Comment: That returns "logical(0)"

Comment: Please Check my answer ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Data

```
PIN <- c("case1", "case2", "case3", "case4", "case5")
STAMP_1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
STAMP_2 <- c(NA, 1, 1, NA, 1)
STAMP_3 <- c(1, NA, 1, 1, NA)
STAMP_4 <- c(NA, NA, 1, 1, NA)
STAMP_5 <- c(1, NA, NA, 1, NA)
dat <- data.frame(PIN, STAMP_1, STAMP_2, STAMP_3, STAMP_4, STAMP_5)
dat
    PIN STAMP_1 STAMP_2 STAMP_3 STAMP_4 STAMP_5
1 case1       1      NA       1      NA       1
2 case2       1       1      NA      NA      NA
3 case3       1       1       1       1      NA
4 case4       1      NA       1       1       1
5 case5       1       1      NA      NA      NA
```

In your case :

```
dat[dat$STAMP_2==1,'STAMP_3']
[1] NA NA  1 NA NA
```

---

The correct way for filter when there is `NA`

Base R

```
dat[which(dat$STAMP_2==1),'STAMP_3']
   [1] NA  1 NA
```

or

`subset(dat, STAMP_2 ==1, select=c('STAMP_3'))`

```
  STAMP_3
2      NA
3       1
5      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to that ADJUSTED_ORR contain the NA values, you can try the example below

```
df <- data.frame(a = NA, b = 1:100)
df[df$a==1,]
```